# Two callbacks fire same time.iOS Push notifications

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I have an issues with firebase push notifications.
When app is in background mode, when push comes this 2 functions call same time

> application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification
> userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler
> completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
>
> func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
> didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler
> completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

when app in forground this 2 methods called

> func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
> willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler
> completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) ->
> Void) {
>
> application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification
> userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler
> completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

My question is
Why we need new ios 10 methods when didReceiveRemoteNotification called in every case, I have tested on iOS 10 phone.

Comment: You can use them both. But the results are unexpected that is you never know when it eventually breaks. It could break on iOS 10.3.2 or iOS 11 or any other versions. So it's best to have an `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { . 
 }` condition and use the `UserNotifications` framework for it and for iOS <10 just use the older versions